# Module not found: Can't resolve ' ./Navbar' error when compiling in react

Tags: reactjs

I am completing a tutorial for an app and when working on the front end I have made a seperate file for the navbar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class Navbar extends Component {

 
  render() {
    return (
     <nav className="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
          <a
            className="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0"
            href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/bootcamp"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            EthSwap
          </a>
        </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

I have imported this file to my App.js file :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Web3 from 'web3'
import Navbar from ' ./Navbar'
import './App.css'
```

When I save and reload the  webpage, I get the following error:

./src/components/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve ' ./Navbar' in 'C:\Users\34632\eth_swap1\src\components'

I am not sure what the problem is as I have gotten past this point yesterday without a problem and now the problem persists. Does anyone know what is going on here?

[image: directory]

Here is my directory.

Here is the App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Web3 from 'web3'
import from ' ./Navbar'
import './App.css'


class App extends Component {

  async componentWillMount()  {
    await this.loadWeb3()
    await this.loadBlockchainData()


  }

  async loadBlockchainData() {
    const web3 = window.web3

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    this.setState({ account: accounts[0] })

    const ethBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.state.account)
    this.setState({ ethBalance })
    console.log(this.state.ethBalance)

  }

  async loadWeb3() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
      await window.ethereum.enable()
    }
    else if (window.web3) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
    }
    else {
      window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying Metamask!')
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      account: '',
      ethBalance: '0'
       

    }

  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.account)
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
          <div className="row">
            <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 d-flex text-center">
              <div className="content mr-auto ml-auto">
                <a
                  href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/bootcamp"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
              
                </a>
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
               
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you update your directory structure?

Comment: done. is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space from the import

from:

```
import Navbar from ' ./Navbar'
```

to:

```
import Navbar from './Navbar';
```

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
▶ 29 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: sure, what exactly do you want me to show you? I will post the whole app.

Comment: You are missing the name of the import, change `import from ' ./Navbar'` to `import Navbar from './Navbar';` in your App.js

Comment: thanks Jesus, I got that. Can you look at this new problem associated to the same Navbar?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67226834/error-when-compiling-in-react-check-the-render-method-of-app?noredirect=1#comment118828350_67226834

Comment: Sure, you should close this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-multi-page-website-using-react-js/ you can get the error OP faced by not structuring the project correctly. Note the error:

> /src/components/App.js Module not found: **Can't resolve ' ./Navbar' in 'C:\Users\34632\eth_swap1\src\components**'

The NavbarElement.js file is located under components/Navbar/ not directly under components/.

See the structure here, the solution is to create a sub-folder "Navbar" under components and move the two js files:

[image]